# Is there a limit for the bonus experience % that you can get?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there a limit for the bonus experience % that you can get?

Say you equip

- Cain's Laurel, socketed with a Star ruby +25%
- 2 other Cain's set items                 +30%
- hellfire ring                            +35%

This will give you 90% bonus experience, is there a limit?

Comment: you can get more then 90% bonus xp from a high level ruby alone, not including the "double gem stat" for leorics crown

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The theorical max value is currently (as of patch 2.0.1) +4682%:

[You can test it here](http://d3resource.com/xpcalc/). With the simulator you can select :

- The Torment level (1 -> 6)
- The gear that brings +x% XP bonus (and the value of this bonus)
- The gear that brings +x% XP bonus on follower (as the follower share 20% with you)
- The number of player (1 -> 4)
- If you have a pool of reflection, a shrine or an event buff active.

Note that some of those bonus are multiplicatives and other additives which is why your total +XP% can show different value for 2 differents 50% bonus XP.

Comment: Actually the cap is 1513%. It's impossible to have a follower in a 4 player game.

Answer (score 1):

- Cains Set : 30%
- Marquis Ruby : 33%
- Leorics Ring : 30%
- Hellfire : 35%
- MP10 : 200%
- HF on follower : 9% XP
- 5 stacks of NV : (5 * 15) = 75 % (Thanks, Wiz)
- Also get the 45% bonus if you
  group with 3 other people. Dont forget that this bonus is
  multiplicative.

So about 457% bonus to XP.
When the expansion hits, there maybe will be better items with more MF, who knows.

Comment: Dont forget Nepahlem stack, I overpass +900% xp with 5 stack NV