# How does XP bonus from Ruby socketed on helms interact with XP bonus from Torment level?

Tags: diablo-iii

With the new difficulty system I was wondering for Torment 6 if it was worth putting a Ruby in my helm instead of increasing my survivability with an Amethyst. How does the bonus from the ruby interact with the new XP bonus from Torment level ? Is it :

- Additive : Put the total of XP bonus in T6 up to 1633% (1600% from T6 + 33% from Ruby) so a monster worth 100 XP now brings 1633 XP
- Multiplicative : A monster worth 100 XP will bring me 1600XP (T6) * 1.33 (Bonus from Ruby) = 2128 XP

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know it's multiplicative - but I can't check myself at the moment. If you can launch the game open the character screen and go to details. At the bottom you should see bonus experience. Equip/Unequip the helm with the gem and you see the difference.

Comment: As far as I know all experience bonuses from items/pools are additive, but I never considered how they interacted with bonuses from difficulty.

Comment: HAve you checked [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/129105/61395)

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau yes since i wrote it =p. But it applies to several concept that no longer exist (Nepahlem valor, Monster Power etc.) and so I don't know if Blizzard reworked the way gear +XP bonus and diffuclty +Xp bonus work together

Comment: Oups, didn't notice but I have not seen anything mentionning, in the patch notes, a change in the xp. I might have miss it but I'm pretty sure I've read nothing on that.

Comment: That said, it answers your base question of what Rubies do, but I'm not sure we have a question about how bonus XP interacts with Torment/Monster Power.

Comment: I rewrote my question so to be more specific and adressm y particular interrogation.